# Exploring code objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, reflection

The first version of my solution was wrong (the usage of `compile()` function), for details see [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55543832/2913477).

The solution has been fixed and now it works correctly. Another approach is used: `my_add.__code__`. The questions stayed the same.

I am reading the book: *Obi Ike-Nwosu. Inside The Python Virtual Machine* and have reached the "Code Objects" chapter. This chapter has all code object fields printed out:

> ```
> co_argcount = 1
> co_cellvars = ()
> co_code = b'|\x00d\x01\x16\x00d\x02k\x02r\x1e|\x00d\x03\x16\x00d\x02k\x02r\x1ed\\
> x04S\x00n,|\x00d\x01\x16\x00d\x02k\x02r0d\x05S\x00n\x1a|\x00d\x03\x16\x00d\x02k\x02r\
> Bd\x06S\x00n\x08t\x00|\x00\x83\x01S\x00d\x00S\x00'
> co_consts = (None, 3, 0, 5, 'FizzBuzz', 'Fizz', 'Buzz')
> co_filename = /Users/c4obi/projects/python_source/cpython/fizzbuzz.py
> co_firstlineno = 6
> co_flags = 67
> etc...
> ```

but there is no explanation how this can be done programatically, so I wrote my own code:

```
# The explored function
def my_add(a,b):
    first = a
    second = b

    return first + second

def print_co_obj_fields(code_obj):
    # Iterating through all instance attributes
    # and calling all having the 'co_' prefix
    for name in dir(code_obj):
        if name.startswith('co_'):
            co_field = getattr(code_obj, name)
            print(f'{name:<20} = {co_field}')

# The function code object (__code__) usage
print_co_obj_fields(my_add.__code__)
```

**Output**

```
co_argcount          = 2
co_cellvars          = ()
co_code              = b'|\x00}\x02|\x01}\x03|\x02|\x03\x17\x00S\x00'
co_consts            = (None,)
co_filename          = ./source.py
co_firstlineno       = 17
co_flags             = 67
co_freevars          = ()
co_kwonlyargcount    = 0
co_lnotab            = b'\x00\x01\x04\x01\x04\x02'
co_name              = my_add
co_names             = ()
co_nlocals           = 4
co_stacksize         = 2
co_varnames          = ('a', 'b', 'first', 'second')
```

Have I done this the optimal way? How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## main guard

Put the parts of your code that are the ones calling for execution behind a `if __name__ == "__main__":` [guard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/1562285)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def my_add(a, b):
        first = a
        second = b

        return first + second
    print_co_obj_fields(my_add.__code__)
```

This way you can import this python module from other places if you ever want to

## Documentation

There is a python convention (`docstring`) to document the behaviour of a method: [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

```
def print_co_obj_fields(code_obj):
    """prints all the instance variables of the code object that start with 'co_'"""
```

## Indentation

To decrease the levels of indentation, you can reverse the test of `startswith`, and `continue` when it fails:

```
def print_co_obj_fields(code_obj):
    # Iterating through all instance attributes
    # and calling all having the 'co_' prefix
    for name in dir(code_obj):
        if not name.startswith('co_'):
            continue
        co_field = getattr(code_obj, name)
        print(f'{name:<20} = {co_field}')
```

An alternative if using the builtin `filter`:

```
def print_co_obj_fields(code_obj):
    # Iterating through all instance attributes
    # and calling all having the 'co_' prefix
    for name in filter(lambda field: field.startswith("co_"), dir(code_obj)):
        co_field = getattr(code_obj, name)
        print(f'{name:<20} = {co_field}')
```

## Presentation

Separate the generation of the results from the presentation. The easiest way to do this is to have `print_co_obj_fields` `yield` the `name` and `co_field` instead of printing them

```
def co_obj_fields(code_obj):
    """generator that yields the fields in a code_object and their value"""
    for name in filter(lambda field: field.startswith("co_"), dir(code_obj)):
        co_field = getattr(code_obj, name)
        yield name, co_field

def print_co_obj_fields(fields):
    for name, co_field in fields:
        print(f"{name:<20} = {co_field}")
```

The `main` part then changes to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    def my_add(a, b):
        first = a
        second = b

        return first + second

    fields = co_obj_fields(my_add.__code__)
    print_co_obj_fields(fields)
```

Comment: "Separate the generation of the results from the presentation." But it means, that I should write the presentation part every time I use `co_obj_fields`. It is good from one point of view - I can customize presentation as needed (it is the main purpose of separation, I think), but it is bad when I need the same formatting everywhere, so I will get the duplication in the code. Or in this case it would be better to wrap the presentation part into another function and call it?

Comment: It would be better to wrap the presentation part in another function and call that. If you follow Brendan Rhodes' [clean architecture](https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#clean-architecture-python) you don't have that function call the `co_obj_fields`, but it just receives the results of that call.